# how to remove the WaterMark from ant design pro v5?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhz1U.png)

How to remove the watermark "nianzai" from ant design pro v5?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Watermark is a property of the `ProLayout` Component (see [link](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/layout/#prolayout)).

In order to remove it, navigate to `src/app.tsx` and remove the part

```js
waterMarkProps: {
  content: initialState?.currentUser?.name,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
waterMarkProps={{
        content: 'Covid.Help',
        fontColor: 'rgba(24,144,255,0.15)',
      }}
```

from `src/layouts/BasicLayout.jsx`